# Runtime Error while using Rviz in a PyQT application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, ros

I am trying to use Rviz (ROS Visualization tool) in my own application written in PyQt4. I am using QTcreator IDE to design the forms and convert it into python code using pyuic4.

Rviz library uses python_qt_binding which inturn uses PyQT or PySide (in my case I have only installed PyQt).

I am trying to initialize Rviz as a QWidget and display it in my application. My application and Rviz widget work fine when run individually, but shows the following error when I try to Import Rviz QWidget into the application.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mainwindow.py", line 38, in <module>
    from RvizInitializer import RViz
  File "/home/parallels/Documents/eclipse/workspace/GUI/src/RvizInitializer.py", line 8, in <module>
    from python_qt_binding.QtGui import *
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .binding_helper import loadUi, QT_BINDING, QT_BINDING_MODULES, QT_BINDING_VERSION  # @UnusedImport
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 252, in <module>
    getattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING_ORDER', None),
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 131, in _load_pyqt
    _named_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
RuntimeError: the PyQt5.QtCore and PyQt4.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class
```

code snippets:

**Rviz initializer**

```
class RViz():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Mainwidget = QWidget()

        self.frame = rviz.VisualizationFrame()


        self.frame.setSplashPath( "" )

        self.frame.initialize()

        reader = rviz.YamlConfigReader()
        config = rviz.Config()
        reader.readFile( config, "/home/parallels/catkin_ws/src/map-toddler/configuration_files/rviz_config_files/karto.rviz" )
        self.frame.load( config )


        self.Mainwidget.setWindowTitle( config.mapGetChild( "Title" ).getValue() )


        self.frame.setMenuBar( None )
        self.frame.setStatusBar( None )
        self.frame.setHideButtonVisibility( False )


        ## Here we create the layout and other widgets in the usual Qt way.
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget( self.frame )

        self.Mainwidget.setLayout(layout)
        #self.Mainwidget.resize(500,500)
        #self.Mainwidget.show()
```

**Importing Rviz Qwidget:**

```
from RvizInitializer import RViz

     class mainwindow():
    def __init__(self):   
               .
               .
             other code
               .
               .
        self.RviZ = RViz()
        self.MappingFrameHndl.SLAMLayout.addWidget(self.RviZ.Mainwidget)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You are mixing PyQt4 and PyQt5, which is not possible. The current version of Rviz obviously uses PyQt5. Official support for Qt4 ended over two years ago, so you should avoid using PyQt4 for new projects.

Comment: @ekhumoro: You are right.. I had to port my entire GUI to PyQt5, and it worked.. Thanks for the hint.